# Sort Alphanumeric DataView Column

Tags: vb.net, sorting, datagridview, datatable, alphanumeric

My DataGridView's **DataSource** is bound to a **DataView**. The DataView is equal to my `dtBills` **DataTable**. Like so:

```
Dim View As New DataView
View.Table = DataSet1.Tables("dtBills")
dgvBills.DataSource = View
```

I have multiple columns in this DataGridView. One in particular has strings and integers as information. When I click on the DataGridView Column Header to sort the column, it sorts as strings like the column on the left:

```
'Curr Col  >>>   ' Wanted Result
10001      >>>   10001
100012     >>>   11000
11000      >>>   12000
110049     >>>   100012
12000      >>>   110049
E-1234     >>>   E-1234
T-12345    >>>   T-1235
T-1235     >>>   T-12345
```

How would I go about sorting a bound DataGridView Column when pressing on the Column Header as I normally would? Should I use my `DataView` to help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a DataGridView is databound it is not possible to use its sorting and it is necessary to sort source data. The sorting is a bit complicated so I need two helper columns.

```
dgvBills.AutoGenerateColumns = False
tbl.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Scol1", GetType(String)))
tbl.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Scol2", GetType(Integer)))
```

The first one will contain a leading letters (or empty string). The second will contain only a number contained in the string. We will sort by `Scol1, Scol2`.

Now we set all comumns to `Programatic` mode ([DataGridViewColumnSortMode Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumnsortmode%28v=vs.100%29.aspx))

```
For Each column As DataGridViewColumn In dgvBills.Columns
    column.SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Programmatic
Next
```

And custom sorting is achieved in a handler of `ColumnHeaderMouseClick` ([DataGridView.Sort Method (IComparer)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wstxtkxs%28v=vs.100%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2)). We will use sorting of the underlying view instead of the Grid sorting.

```
Private Sub dgvBills_ColumnHeaderMouseClick(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs) Handles dgvBills.ColumnHeaderMouseClick
    Dim newColumn As DataGridViewColumn = dgvBills.Columns(e.ColumnIndex)

    Dim direction As ListSortDirection
    Dim Modifier As String = ""

    If newColumn.HeaderCell.SortGlyphDirection = SortOrder.Ascending Then
        direction = ListSortDirection.Descending
        Modifier = " desc"
    Else
        direction = ListSortDirection.Ascending
    End If

    Dim View As DataView = dgvBills.DataSource

    If {"JobNumber", "JobNumber1"}.Contains(dgvBills.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).Name) Then
        View.Table.Columns("Scol2").Expression = String.Format("Convert(iif (substring({0},1,2) like '*-',substring({0},3,len({0})-1),{0}), 'System.Int32')", dgvBills.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).Name)
        View.Table.Columns("Scol1").Expression = String.Format("iif (substring({0},1,2) like '*-',substring({0},1,2),'')", dgvBills.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).Name)
        View.Sort = String.Format("Scol1 {0},Scol2 {0}", Modifier)
    Else
        dgvBills.Sort(newColumn, direction)
    End If

    If direction = ListSortDirection.Ascending Then
        newColumn.HeaderCell.SortGlyphDirection = SortOrder.Ascending
    Else
        newColumn.HeaderCell.SortGlyphDirection = SortOrder.Descending
    End If

End Sub
```

In `{"JobNumber", "JobNumber1"}.Contains ...`  is possible to set columns which are sorted differntly. Other columns are sorted as the Grid sorts them by default or it is possible to create another custom sorting.

Note: I have fully working example but I hope that fragments are good enough.

Comment: A few questions here ... You manually added Scol1 and Scol2 ... Am I supposed to create another column named JobNumber1 in my DataTable? Also, when you do `substring({0}, 1, 2)` in the expression, what is that supposed to return? Thanks!

Comment: On the first expression of `Scol2` where we utilize the `String.Format("Convert( ...)"` I get the following error: `Input string was not in a correct format.`

Comment: You've mentioned that there is 19 columns to be sorted. `JobNumber1` is an example (placeholder) of other columns. `substring({0}, 1, 2)` is supposed to return first two characters (e.g. T-) of the column which is sorted - the name is `dgvBills.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).Name`. I am not sure whether all string formats are present in you example. Can you say which string cause the errro?

Comment: The following like causes the error: `View.Table.Columns("Scol2").Expression = String.Format("Convert(Iif(substring({0},1,2) like '*-',substring({0},3,len({0})-1),{0}), 'System.Int32')", DataGridView1.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).Name)`

Comment: The exception `Input string was not in a correct format.` is caused by data in DataTable. I suppose that string is either a number or a number preceded by character and -. Would you please try the data from question/first answer? Or try to decrease number of rows in table to isolate wrong ones.

Comment: Using your original data with the current code, it works perfectly. Although, when I use my DataTable values from the Database, that's where it has an issue ...

Comment: There should be a value which doesn't comply with my simple rules. There probably is a value which contains non numeric character on position 3 or higher.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37116/discussion-between-alex-and-ivanh)

Answer (score 1):

The column is sorted correctly as strings and I suppose you want to sort it as numbers.  The problem is that it seems that the strings you have combine numbers and characters. The result is necessity rather complex sorting for a `DataView`.

```
Dim tbl As New DataTable("dtBills")
Dim DataSet1 As New DataSet
DataSet1.Tables.Add(tbl)
tbl.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("MyCol", GetType(String)))
Dim vals As String() = {"10001", "100012", "11000", "110049", "12000", "E-1234", "T-12345", "T-1235"}
For qq = 0 To vals.Length - 1
    Dim row As DataRow
    row = tbl.NewRow
    row(0) = vals(qq)
    tbl.Rows.Add(vals(qq))
Next
tbl = DataSet1.Tables("dtBills")
tbl.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Scol2", GetType(Integer)) With {.Expression = "Convert(iif (substring(MyCol,1,2) like '*-',substring(MyCol,3,len(MyCol)-1),MyCol), 'System.Int32')"})
tbl.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Scol1", GetType(String)) With {.Expression = "iif (substring(MyCol,1,2) like '*-',substring(MyCol,1,2),'')"})
Dim View As New DataView(tbl)
View.Sort = "Scol1,Scol2"
View.Table = DataSet1.Tables("dtBills")
```

So two new columns are added. The first maintain sorting by initial letters the second to enable sorting by the number contained in the a string.

Comment: I see. This would work if I only sorted Alphanumerically on one column ... Is there another way which would sort like this for every column (19 columns) ?  If I'd do it this way, I'd have many columns to create and wouldn't that impact performance? For example, longer loading time, longer row-filtering on my DataView ?

Comment: Also, I can't get your code to work ... Something is odd with your use of the substring method :p

Comment: I suppose that the column you want to sort has name MyCol. It is necessary to change it to your name. I try to figure out something more flexible. Do I understad sorting correctly? By number (if there is), By the first letter and by number after letter.

Comment: Yes I changed `MyCol` to my column's name `JobNumber` but your substring method seems to hold 3 parameters while it usually holds 2 ... In any case, yes you understand the way I want it to sort. There might only be on issue ... After separating the integers and strings, what if the strings have T-12340, T-1235 ... It will still be displayed and sorted as a string ... Even If T-1235 comes before T-12340

Comment: @Alex - Substring can take either 2 or 3 parameters.  With 2 parameters, the substring returned begins at the supplied start value and returns to the end of the string.  If 3 parameters are supplied, the 3rd parameter is the number of characters to return.

Comment: I have added complete code to answer (as it works on my computer)

Comment: @IvanH I just tested you new solution. It works when I start the program, but as soon as I click on the header to sort ASC / DESC it goes back to what it is doing normally ... :s

Comment: @IvanH Also, when I try to use my columns "JobNumber" instead of "MyCol" it says the entered string is invalid. My column JobNumber is gotten from the DataTable ... But I do not include strings such as Substring("JobNumber", 1, 2) ... I leave it as you left MyCol, without quotes. Is that ok?